# echo <h1> in <title> with php possible

Tags: php, html

is it possible to echo (hope this is the right term) the content of the h1 tag to the title tag on a **non database** driven xhtml strict site?
Example:

`<h1>Green Soup</h1>` would automatically displayed in the

title tag `<title>Today's Menu: [echo h1 tag]</title>`

with the result `title>Today's Menu: Green Soup</title>`

The site I'm working on has a php script that rotates content on a daily base, ie. today is "green soup" and tomorrow "BLT Sandwiches", etc ... with a static header and so far statc title.

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm just getting started in the php world.
Thank you in advance

Comment: This would probably be best done by modifying the origional php script... rather than adding another snippet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just define a variable and echo it out in PHP.

```
<?php $title="Green Soup"; ?>
<title>Today's Menu: <?php echo $title; ?></title>
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

It sounds like you're already using PHP on this page, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on where you create that `<h1>` tag and where you have the `<title>` tag echoed out. If you can get the content for the `<h1>` tag before you echo the `<title>` tag, then you can echo that out.